# How order of divisor with support at infinity is changed at reduction?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, abelian-varieties, finite-fields, curves, hyperelliptic-curves

Jing Yu in his paper "[On Arithmetic Of Hyperelliptic Curves](http://swc-alpha.math.arizona.edu/swc-www/aws/1998/98Yu.pdf)" on page 5 asserts the following

> The most interesting case is certainly the case $k = \mathbb Q$ and $D \in \mathbb Z[t]$.
>
> To decide whether there are non-constant units in $\mathbb Q[t, \sqrt{D}]$, one reduces the equation $y^2 = D(t)$ modulo various odd primes $p$. For all but finitely many $p$ (namely those dividing the discriminant of the polynomial $D(t)$), one obtains curve $C_p$ over the finite field $\mathbb F_p$. Given such a prime $p$ of "good" reduction. If the divisor class of $\infty_{+} - \infty_{-}$ is of order $n$ in $Jac\ C$, then unless $p | n$, the t is also of order $n$ in $Jac\ C_p$. This fact follows from the theory of reduction of abelian varieties.

I wonder where is it possible to read the proof of mentioned fact or some similar theory. Could you please provide some links to papers or books in which I can read that this fact follows from the theory of reduction of abelian varieties. Or it would be great if it is possible to explain it right here.

P.S. $C$ is a hyperelliptic curve over the base field $k = \mathbb Q$, $D$ is a square free polynomial with $\deg D$ is even, positive and the leading coefficient of $D$ is a square in $k^{\times}$.

Comment: Section 3 of Lang-Tate "Principal homogeneous spaces over abelian varieties" discusses that the specialization map for abelian varieties induces isomorphisms on $n$-torsion points if $n$ is not divisible by the residue characteristic and the abelian variety has good reduction. The link between the Jacobian of reduction and the reduction of the Jacobian should be discussed in Bosch-Lütkebohmert-Raynaud "Néron models".